# How is the variable "data" accessible before its declared?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was playing around with express when i noticed something unexpected.
Heres my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('response string');
    console.log(data)
});


const data = {
    key: 'value'
};


app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Quote API listening on port 3000!'));
```

This prints // { key: 'value' }

I mean, functions work this way due to hoisting(?) but variables should not.
As the title suggests, how is the variable "data" accessible in the lines before it's declared?

Comment: Your `app.get` is obviously called after you have declared `data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't accessed until the function passed to `get` is **called** … which is after the constant is declared (i.e. when a GET request for `/` is recieved).

Nothing to do with hoisting.